# How to check if table in Snowflake is empty and get response for it - Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake database with Spring Boot in my project.

I have written a query in Java that queries the Snowflake temporary table and then copies that data in CVS format to S3.

Everything works fine until there is a user with no Snowflake data.
Then the temporary table that was created is empty and no data is being copied in S3 which gives an error from S3 that `objectKey is not found`

So I was thinking to first create temporary table and then to check it if is empty.
If is not empty, copy data to S3 if it is, return error.

I have this code for creating temporary table

```
public void getUser(String userId, String dbName) {

String q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE \"TEST_DATABASE\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" AS SELECT \"USERID\", \"FIRSTNAME\", \"LASTNAME\" from \"TEST_DATABASE\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER\"";

jdbcTemplatePerBrand.values().forEach(tab -> tab.query(q, s -> {}));

}
```

Then I was thinking to add this part of code to check if table is empty:

```
String ifTableEmpty = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM \"TEST_DATABASE\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\") THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsEmpty;\n";

jdbcTemplatePerBrand.get(brandAfterMigration).query(ifTableEmpty, s -> {});

if(ifTableEmpty.equals("0")){
 System.out.println("");
}
```

From above query I am not getting any result in way of 0 or 1 (Which I would like).

When I run a query to check if the table is empty in Snowflake, I get this result:

[image]

But I don't know how to get that result back to my code.

Comment: Why not just a **SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM <table>**? If the table is empty count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<schema_name>'
     AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>';
```

Or use SHOW TABLES and get the result using result_scan:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'pattern';

SELECT rows
  FROM TABLE (result_scan (last_query_id ()));
```

Reference: [INFORMATION SCHEMA.TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html), [SHOW TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-tables.html), [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html)